# Can't insert/remove a blank page in main document

Tags: input, include, blank-page

I'm on Win7 with TeX Live 2013 and TeXstudio. I have a `main.tex` file (`\documentclass[...]{scrartcl}`) with 2 `\input{file}` commands. I want to **put a blank page** between the table of contents and the beginning of the 1st file *and* **remove** the extra blank page that TeX Live keeps adding somewhere *before* the 2nd file or in the *middle of it!*

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\campoE}{\mathcal{E}\ped{x}}
\newcommand{\derivata}[2]{\frac{\textup{d}{#1}}{\textup{d}{#2}} }
\newcommand{\derivataparziale}[2]{\dfrac{\partial{#1}}{\partial {#2}} }
\newcommand{\integrale}[4]{\displaystyle \int_{#3}^{#4}#1\,\text{d}{#2} }

%----------------------------------
\title{E.S.S.}
\author{Wobby Windows}
\date{Written on some day}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\input{captest}
\clearpage
\input{formule}
\end{document}
```

`captest.tex`

```
\newpage
\section{Test}

\subsection{Introduzione lipsum}

\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Effetto lipsum}

\lipsum[3-4]
```

`formule.tex`

```
\section{Formule}

\begin{align}
\label{7.1.1} I\ped{c} &= \dfrac{q\tilde{D\ped{n}} n\ped{i}^{2} A\ped{E} \, \exp\left({ q V\ped{BE} / kT}\right) }{\integrale{p}{x}{0}{x_B} } & \\
\label{7.1.2} \derivataparziale{I_C}{V\ped{CB}}&= \dfrac{-q\tilde{D\ped{n}} n\ped{i}^{2} A\ped{E} \, \exp\left({qV\ped{BE}/kT}\right) \, p(x_B) }{\left[\integrale{p}{x}{0}{x_B} \right]^{2}} \, \derivataparziale{x_B}{V\ped{CB}}&\\
\label{7.1.3} \derivataparziale{I\ped{C}}{V\ped{CB}}&= -I\ped{C}\,p(x\ped{B}) \; \dfrac{1}{\integrale{p}{x}{0}{x\ped{B}}} \, \bigg [\derivataparziale{x\ped{B}}{V\ped{CB}} \bigg] &\\
  \notag &= {} -\dfrac{I\ped{C}}{V\ped{A}}=\dfrac{I_C}{|V_A|}\\
\label{7.1.4} V\ped{A}&= \dfrac{\integrale{p}{x}{0}{x_B} }{p(x\ped{B}) \derivataparziale{x\ped{B}}{V\ped{CB}}}\\
\label{eq:7.1.5-6}  \integrale{p}{x}{0}{x\ped{B}}&=\dfrac{Q\ped{B}}{q} \qquad \qquad q\, p(x\ped{B}) \, \derivata{x_B}{V\ped{CB}}=\derivata{Q_B}{V\ped{CB}}\\
\label{eq:7.1.7-8} \bigg| \derivata{Q_B}{V\ped{CB}} \bigg|&= C\ped{jc} \qquad \qquad  |V\ped{A}|= \dfrac{Q\ped{B}}{C\ped{jC}}\\
\label{7.2.1} I_B&= I_0\, \exp\left({\dfrac{qV\ped{BE}}{nkT}}\right)  \\
\label{7.2.2} \integrale{p(x)}{x}{0}{x\ped{B}}&=\integrale{[N\ped{a}(x) + \, n'(x)]}{x}{0}{x\ped{B}}\\
\label{7.2.3} n(0) &=\dfrac{N\ped{a}(0)}{2} \left[ \bigg(1+ \dfrac{4 \, n^{2}\ped{i} \, \exp\left({qV\ped{BE}/kT}\right) }{N\ped{a}(0)} \bigg)^{1/ \,2} -1 \right] \\
\label{7.2.4} \derivata{\campoE}{x}&=\dfrac{1}{\epsilon\ped{s}} \left[  q\,N(x) - \dfrac{J_C}{v(x)} \right]\\
\label{7.2.5}  V\ped{CB}+\phi \ped{i}&=\integrale{-\campoE}{x}{x_B}{x_C}\\
\label{7.2.6} J\ped{l}&=q\, N(x)\, v(x)\\
\label{7.2.7} \integrale{x \; \derivata{\campoE}{x}}{x}{x\ped{B}}{x\ped{C}}&=\dfrac{1}{\epsilon\ped{s}}\, \integrale{x\, \left[ qN(x) - \dfrac{J_C}{v(x)}\right]}{x}{x_B}{x_C}\\
\label{7.2.8} \integrale{x}{\campoE}{x_B}{x_C}&= - \integrale{\campoE}{x}{x_B}{x_C}=V\ped{CB} + \phi_i\\
\label{7.2.9} V\ped{CB}&= \dfrac{1}{\epsilon_s} \integrale{x \, \left[q \, N(x) - \dfrac{J_C}{v(x)} \right]}{x}{x_B}{x_C} - \phi_i\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\label{7.2.10} V\ped{CB}&= \dfrac{1}{2\, \epsilon_s} \left[ qN\ped{epi} + \dfrac{J_C}{v_l}\right]\, x\ped{CB}^2  - \phi_i\\
\notag &= \dfrac{q N\ped{epi}}{2 \epsilon_s} \left[ 1+ \dfrac{J_C}{J_l}\right]\, x^2_{CB} -\phi_i\\
\label{7.2.13} I_C&=I\ped{S} \; \exp{\left[ \dfrac{q (V\ped{BE} - I\ped{B}R\ped{B})}{kT}  \right] }\\
\label{7.3.1} Q\ped{nB} &= \integrale{q \,A\ped{E} \, n'(x) }{x}{0}{x_B}\\
\label{7.3.2} \tau_B &= \dfrac{Q_{nB}}{I_{C}}\\
\label{7.3.3} \tau_B &= \dfrac{x_{B}^2 }{2 \tilde{D}_{n}}\\
\label{7.3.4} \tau_{B} &= \dfrac{\integrale{p}{x}{0}{x_{B}} \, \integrale{n'}{x}{0}{x_{B}}}{\tilde{D_n} \, n^{2}_{i}\, \exp{\left(qV_{BE} / \, kT\right)}}\\
\label{7.3.5} \tau_{B} &=\dfrac{\tfrac{1}{2} n'(0) x_{B} \left[ \tfrac{1}{2} (n'(0) +2N_{A} ) x_{B} \right]}{\tilde{D} \left[ n'(0) (n'(0) + N_{a} )\right]} =\\
\notag &= \dfrac{x^2_{B}}{4 \tilde{D_n}} \left[ 1 + \dfrac{N_a}{n'(0) + N_a}\right]\\
\label{7.3.6} n(x) &= -\dfrac{J_n}{q\tilde{D_n} p(x) } \, \integrale{p(\xi)}{\xi}{x}{x_B} \\
\label{7.3.7} \tau_B&= \dfrac{1}{\tilde{D_n}} \integrale{\dfrac{1}{p(x)} \left[ \integrale{p(\xi)}{\xi}{x}{x_B}\right]}{x}{0}{x_B}\\
 \label{7.3.8}\tau_B &= \dfrac{x^2}{\tilde{D_n}} \left\lbrace \integrale{\dfrac{1}{p(y)} \left[ \integrale{p(\xi)}{\xi}{y}{1}\right]}{y}{0}{1}\right\rbrace\\
 \notag &= \dfrac{x^2_B}{\nu \, \tilde{D_n}}
\end{align}
```

Is there a way to force TeX Live to do what I want? I just want the 2nd file to start on a new page, not insert a blank page. Since I'm still writing stuff in the 1st file, its length is yet not definitive.

1. Could that be the problem?
2. What is the difference between `\clearpage` and `\newpage`?

**PS**
After problem n.2 was solved still trying to solve problem n1: how to put a blank page right after the table-of-contents?

Comment: `\clearpage` flushes out all floats as well as forcing a pagebreak, `\newpage` just forces a page. `\input` has no effect on page breaking, it is just as if the file contents were at that point, so your example gives no indication of why a page break happens or does not happen, it all depends on the unseen code.

Comment: Please _always_ post a complete example starting with `\documentclass` so people can test any answer

Comment: latex rarely makes a blank page, the most common reason is that you have `\chapter` and the (default) openright option in which case `\chapter` uses `\cleardoublepage` to make sure it starts on an odd numbered page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The OP uses `scrartcl` as `article` substitution, so no default `openright` and no `\chapter` (I know, that you know, but perhaps the OP doesn’t).

Comment: Hi again! I've added a link at the bottom of my question so you can download a zip file containing all the needed files (thanks to Dropbox). My problem is that I can't put a blank page in place of **page 2** AND I can't get rid of that extra page (**page 8** in the pdf) that precedes the formulae section. I've changed `\newpage` to `\clearpage` before giving `\input{cap7_formule}`. I wish I could put less personal info up on the Web with a minimal working example (MWE) but I don't think I can do without the formulae since it is a core part of the problem!

Comment: i'm not exactly sure how `\section` in `scrartcl` works, but you are starting the section in `cap7_formule.tex` with a very large `align` block.  it's large enough that it's pulling the section heading over to a new page.  you can use `\allowdisplaybreaks` to permit the aligned material to break between lines whenever the page reaches capacity.  simply adding that before the first `align` gets rid of the extra page, although i'm not entirely sure of the details.  you probably want more control than that; should be more details in the `amsmath` users guide (`texdoc amsmath`).

Comment: @Speravir -- thanks for the def, but there's still too much that's internal to `scrartcl` for me to figure out definitively *why* what's happening is happening, without serious digging in an unfamiliar `.cls` file.  i'll just give a suggestion on how to get around the problem, but if uncontrolled display breaks aren't wanted (and i think they are not), i don't have time at the moment to research the antidote.  but i'll put in the basics.

Comment: @WobbyWindows Your latest edit was insufficient. See my edit to know what I meant.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind, next time. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks to everybody for their help and especially to **barbara beeton** for the work-around that solved my 2nd problem too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are starting the section in `cap7_formule.tex` with a very large align block.
t's large enough that it's pulling the section heading over to a new page.

you can use `\allowdisplaybreaks` to permit the aligned material to break
between lines whenever the page reaches capacity.

if you enter that in the preamble, it will be in effect throughout the entire document.
if you insert it just before the `align` that is a problem, you can localize it by
wrapping the affected area in braces.  and you will need only one `align`, rather than
the multiple groups that you have now. if there are places you *don't* want a break,
insert `\nobreak` after the `\\` that separates the two lines that shouldn't be
split apart.

adding `\allowdisplaybreaks` will get rid of the extra page.
(if you can add a minimal example, this explanation will probably make more sense to
other readers of this question.)

unfortunately, i'm not sufficiently familiar with `scrartcl` to understand or explain
exactly why this is happening, but this workaround should get rid of the
immediate problem.

**edit:** to add a blank page after the table of contents, since `scrartcl` defaults to
one-sided, you'll have to insert that yourself.  add this after `\tableofcontents`:

```
\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage
```

`\newpage` doesn't actually put anything onto the page, and a page with nothing on it
won't be output.  thus the need for `\mbox` before the second `\newpage`.

Comment: Someone forgot their capital letters ...... :-)

Comment: @azetina that's how we know it's the real Barbara not an imposter.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess its here signature mark. No edits ppl...ok.

Comment: @azetina: Look into her user profile …

Comment: **barbara beeton** thanks for your input - it solved problem n2. Any idea how to solve problem n1 (placing a blank page after the title and table of contents)?

Comment: @WobbyWindows -- add the line `\cleardoublepage` immediately after `\tableofcontents`.  assuming your table of contents ends on a right-hand (odd-numbered) page, following it by `\cleardoublepage` should give you a blank page.  but if the toc ends on a left-hand (even-numbered) page, `\cleardoublepage will only go to a new right-hand page, because that's where chapters are usually expected to start.

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` is not working. I have title + toc in p.1. In p.2 the text from `cap7.tex` starts, even if I give that command you suggested. I tried with some dummy text instead of the two tex files, still not working.

Comment: @WobbyWindows -- i just registered the fact that you are using `scrartcl`, a class intended for production of an article, not a book.  so it wouldn't make sense to support `\cleardoublepage` in the same way it is done for a book class.  someone more familiar with this class can undoubtedly give you better guidance, but here is a suggestion (a hack, generally not recommended): issue the commands `\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage` after `\tableofcontents`.  but this will add an empty page even if your toc goes to two pages, in which case another manual change will be needed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: It’s onesided design anyway, so no need for different handling. (And I thought the OP had solved this already … was an error obviously.) Edit this into your answer. BTW: I think two `\newpage` would suffice after the TOC.

Comment: @Speravir -- thanks for alerting me to the fact that `scrartcl` is by default one-sided; two-sided articles are what i'm used to.  however, using just two `\newpage`s isn't enough -- `\newpage` doesn't put anything on a blank page that would allow it to be set.  but an `\mbox{}` will do the trick.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: To the last: Emm, yes. It was misunderstandable. I meant this in contrast to twice `\clearpage`, what you used in your comment above mine.